# Dockerfile FROM command doesn't get image from insecure private registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I can't find docs anywhere describing whether the "FROM" Dockerfile command will automatically pull from a remote private registry, or whether you must do an explicit "docker pull" first before running "docker build".

I have an insecure private registry set up at http://192.168.1.1:5000. It is configured in /etc/docker/daemon.json. Pushes and pulls both work against this insecure registry.

But if an image doesn't exist in the local cache (i.e., it hasn't been pulled and doesn't already exist from a previous docker build) then when running docker build the Dockerfile FROM command results in:

```
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for 192.168.1.1:5000/reponame  0.1s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for 192.168.1.1:5000/reponame:latest:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to do request: Head "https://192.168.1.1:5000/v2/reponame/manifests/latest": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

Strange that it is trying HTTPS even though it *should* know that the registry is insecure and thus use HTTP.

Anyway, is this normal behavior?  Do I just need to always perform a "docker pull" for an image before attempting to reference it in a Dockerfile FROM command?  Or am I missing something that would make this work without doing a pull first?

Answer (score 1):

Posting answer for anyone who might run into this in the future. I finally found the root cause of this issue. Apparently the standard docker registry image doesn't respond to the http HEAD requests that DOCKER_BUILDKIT sends.

The workaround is to disable buildkit (set DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 in environment). This falls back to the pre-buildkit logic, which doesn't make that HEAD call before pulling the image.  Less efficient (and you lose some other buildkit advantages), but it works.

Alternatively, you can issue a pull command for the image before running the docker build, and FROM will pull from the local cache.

Comment: That's not really fixing the issue. Did you get another way to perform the pull with build kit recently?